# BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(...) with templated function on templated container

Tags: c++, templates, boost, type-traits, boost-phoenix

I need a lazy evaluating version of std::pair.first. My approach is to use boost::phoenix, define a templated function and use the BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION makro as folows:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 first_impl(std::pair<T1,T2> p){
    return p.first;
}
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(std::string, first, first_impl, 1);
```

which is *fine for the specific case I need in my current program* (in my case T1 = std::string). But how can I use the  result type T1 of the first_impl function template to abstract this even more for future use? [The documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function/adapting_functions.html#phoenix.modules.function.adapting_functions.boost_phoenix_adapt_function) mentions the use of `typename remove_reference<A0>::type` as first argument to the makro to define the return type of the function to be the type of its first argument. Based on this I tried several versions like:

```
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(typename A0::first_type, first, first_impl, 1);
```

trying to access [`std::pair<T1, T2>::first_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) which doesn't seem to work for me.

Additionaly I tried to adapt what [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) does to deal with this like follows

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> first_type < std::pair<T1,T2> > 
{ typedef T1 type; }
```

but this doesn't seem to work either. 
Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest a trait, indeed like you almost had with `first_type`:

```
namespace detail // by convention, hide details from enclosing namespace
{
    template <typename Pair, typename First = typename std::remove_reference<Pair>::type::first_type> 
    struct first_type {
        typedef First type;
    };

// Now you can use the trait in your `first_impl` return type:

    template <typename Pair>
    typename first_type<Pair>::type first_impl(Pair const& p){
        return p.first;
    }
}
```

Now, you can indeed use in the adaption:

```
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(typename detail::first_type<A0>::type, first, detail::first_impl, 1)
```

Fully working demo: See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12c2bb7a71b3b420)**

```
int main()
{
    using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;

    std::map<std::string, int> const m { 
        { "one",   1 },
        { "two",   2 },
        { "three", 3 },
        { "four",  4 }
    };

    std::for_each(begin(m), end(m), std::cout << first(arg1) << "\n");
}
```

Output

```
four
one
three
two
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works fine for me. I still need to learn more about solving such problems with templates / traits.

Comment: Additional info: It might have been a problem due to the specific way in which Phoenix _explicitely instantiates_ the member template function `operator()`. I think it explicitly passes 1 (single) template argument (the `pair`) which explains why it wouldn't work with your method template (that expects 2 arguments). I didn't investigate, because I don't usually like to 'swim upstream' - I just take the road that I know works (hopefully I usually know the path of least resistance... :))